# Linear layout alignment Issue

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I need to have various text view on a single line. And I want then to be in single line centered. As if they are written in single text view. So I used Linear layouts. But my **problem** is when i am tilting it to portrait orientation, text are **dropping vertically. I want** that if text are not fitting in screen then they must **come to next line CENTERED** on tilt. My problem is somewhat same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596493/linear-layout-is-not-keeping-text-view-in-center. Please can any body help in this. My layout.xml is as below.....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

//some code here


    <LinearLayout 
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="horizontal"
             android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
             android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_jobs_info_note" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textColor="#000000" 
            android:text="@string/jobs_info_note"
            android:textSize="20dp" 
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
             />

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_my_job" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="@string/my_job"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:textColor="#0000FF" 
            android:onClick="onWorkListClick"
            android:textSize="20dp" 
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
             />

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_jobs_info_note_mid" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textColor="#000000" 
            android:text="@string/jobs_info_note_mid"
            android:textSize="20dp" 
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
             />

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_team_job" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textColor="#0000FF"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="onWorkListClick"
            android:text="@string/team_job"
            android:textSize="20dp" 
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
             />

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_jobs_info_note_end" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="@string/jobs_info_note_end"
            android:textColor="#000000" 
            android:textSize="20dp" 
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
             />

        </LinearLayout>
        //Some more code here
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_current_job_map" 
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/map" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Is there some other way to do this,Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: My suggestion would be to use `Relative Layout` and you can use attributes like `align_toLeftOf` etc. to place your `TextViews` next to each other. Avoid nesting layouts as much as you can.

Comment: I was using that only earlier, but the entire line was not coming in centre.

Comment: What do you exactly mean when you say **center**?

Comment: Center mean center of screen of emulator. First word appears in center. and rest is aligned accordingly

Comment: And apart from that when layout is made center its producing same result.

Comment: Your landscape view is perfect one, Right?

Comment: You can use `android:gravity="center"` and `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`, and then go about it.

Comment: Yes its working fine,simply because length is not exceeding screen size, When I am increasing the size of text, in landscape also its dropping

Comment: @Ghost No, When I am using android:gravity="center" and android:layout_centerInParent="true" text are overwriting each other

Comment: @AbhishekSharma: Use both attributes on only one `TextView` field. Esp the one which is supposed to be the starting point. Rest of the fields can be relative to this field.

Comment: @Ghost No sir, Its still the same. aligning first text in centre and rest like earlier.

Comment: @AbhishekSharma: Can you please post a screenshot of your desired layout? Like how it should look.. And also post the screenshot of the layout that you're getting right now. I'll try helping.

Comment: see screen shot of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596493/linear-layout-is-not-keeping-text-view-in-center. I want exactly like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using different font size. Although its not the correct way but still there was no option left.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView6"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView7"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

All you've to do is place `TextViews` relative to each other like this, and I believe this should work. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for taking so much pain, but this code is cutting those text which are not coming in the same line. That mean those text which were falling vertically are not appearing in screen now.